# How db_query works when I pass query parameter directly

Tags: 7, database

I have one doubt for [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x) in drupal 7, as in [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x) db_query syntax is like

```
$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created
FROM {node} n WHERE n.uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $uid));
```

But what happens when I write query like.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created
FROM {node} n WHERE n.uid = $uid");
```

- **Is it still convert in PDO prepared statements?**
- **Is it still reliable as first query?**
- **Will it handle SQL injection?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No
2. Do you mean "is it a syntactically valid query"? If `$uid` is an integer or string that forms the remainder of a syntactically correct query then yes, otherwise no
3. Very much no

In short, don't do that. Use the API as the documentation says to, or you'll be susceptible to bugs and security holes.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Writing secure code for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2489544) (same for D7)

> ### Use the database abstraction layer to avoid SQL injection attacks
>
> Use the database layer correctly. For example, never concatenate data
> directly into SQL queries.
>
> **Don't do this:**
>
> ```
> db_query('SELECT foo FROM {table} t WHERE t.name = '. $_GET['user']);
> ```
>
> **Instead, use proper argument substitution with db_query**. The DB layer works on top of PHP PDO and uses an array of named placeholders:
>
> ```
> db_query("SELECT foo FROM {table} t WHERE t.name = :name", [':name' => $_GET['user']]);
> ```

Comment: Good shout, didn't think there would be anything quite so perfectly applicable in the official docs